# Group by Row to column in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

In SQL Server, I have maintained the following details:

| S.No | Parent_ID | Child_ID | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 4 | NULL | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 | 7 | 1 |
| 7 | NULL | 1 | 2 |
| 8 | 1 | 7 | 3 |
| 9 | 7 | 9 | 1 |

Required table like below.

| QTY | Child_ID | Groups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1,2 |
| 4 | 3 | 1,2,3 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 | 5,6 |
| 1 | 7 | 5,6,7 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 7 | 1,7 |
| 1 | 9 | 1,7,9 |

I tried with this code, but I am getting a recursion error:

```
WITH GroupTable (Qty, Child_ID, Parent_ID,  Groups) AS
(
    SELECT 
        S.Qty, S.Child_ID, S.Parent_ID, 
        CONVERT(varchar(100), S.Child_ID) AS path
    FROM 
        tabel1 AS S 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        S.Qty, S.Child_ID, p.Parent_ID,  
        CONVERT(varchar(100), (RTRIM(p.Groups) + ',' + 
                              CONVERT(varchar(100), S.Child_ID)))
    FROM 
        GroupTable AS p 
    JOIN 
        tabel1 AS S ON S.Parent_ID = p.Child_ID
)
SELECT
    Qty, Child_ID, Groups 
FROM
    GroupTable 
WHERE
    Parent_ID IS NULL
```

I'm getting this error:

> Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The statement terminated.
> The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what is Groups in required result?

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the `MAXRECURSION` cap because you are getting more rows, then you are expecting - probably because your bossiness logic or/and data is not well defined.

For example, for child `2` you need parent `1` but in your base data you have two records for parent `1`, so you have more rows after the first iteration of the CTE:

[image]

But in your final result, you are want the data from this group only:

[image]

With your real data you may find more cases like this, and it will be difficult to filter all of them in the final `SELECT` or you just may have wrong data.

So, you need to think how to define this groups, because currently is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

For your maximum recursion problem, you can use:

```
FROM GroupTable
  option (maxrecursion 0)
```